# Shorte.st Api python

Tags: python, api

i was trying to use the shorte.st api to automatically create my short links using my python progam, but i really don't know how to use the Apis! 
In the dedicated page there is only this code here:

```
curl H "public-api-token: ---" -X -d "urlToShorten=google.com" PUT http://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url {"status":"ok","shortenedUrl":"http:\/\/sh.st\/XXXX"}
```

In the public-api-token i have to insert my private token obviously, but since curl is for c (i think) how can i use them with python? 
Thanks so much

Comment: You can try executing this curl command using `subprocess` module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to use python lib called requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for http requests. All you have to do is to send an url that you'd like shorten as data dict and your public api token in headers under the key of "public-api-token". You can find your api token on https://shorte.st/tools/api page. Response content comes as a json encoded string, so you need to decode it to obtain dict object.

```
import requests
response = requests.put("https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url", {"urlToShorten":"google.com"}, headers={"public-api-token": "your_api_token"})
print response.content
>>> {"status":"ok","shortenedUrl":"http:\\/\\/sh.st\\/ryHyU"}
import json
decoded_response = json.loads(response.content)
print decoded_response
>>>{u'status': u'ok', u'shortenedUrl': u'http://sh.st/ryHyU'}
```

Answer (score 0):

And to print out just the created URL use...

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.put("https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url", {"urlToShorten":"google.com"}, headers={"public-api-token": "85d3636f48c112de6e413865afc177b5"})
decoded_response = json.loads(response.content)
print(decoded_response['shortenedUrl'])
```